# Numerical stability in the product of many matrices

Tags: matrix, stability, floating-point, numpy, precision

I have to calculate in numpy the matrix-product of many matrices (~400). Are there common practices to increase numerical stability?

If this is relevant, the matrices are $300\times 300$ orthogonal projection matrices.

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a bit more about what do you mean "to increase numerical stability"?

Comment: I refer to errors stemming from finite precision, as getting infinitesimal numbers when multiplying many numbers smaller than 1.

Comment: By "300 by 300 orthogonal projection matrices" do you mean that your matrices are orthogonal matrices or that they or matrices that can be used to perform orthogonal projections onto subspaces?

Comment: The latter option.

Comment: In that case, your matrices aren't orthogonal matrices and the answer by @whpowell96 isn't relevant.

Comment: You're starting with a 300 dimensional space, and each projection would reduce this dimension by at least one.  Unless there's significant repition in this sequence of projections, you'd be left with only the 0 vector after 400 projections.  Could you explain where this problem is coming from?

Comment: Yes, in practice I work with matrices of different dimensions, and the number of products changes accordingly; 300x300 matrices are multiplied about 100 times. The problem comes from a research in ML, and each projection matrix in the product should remove a different kind of information from the input vectors.

Answer (score 5):

Orthogonal matrices are about as well-conditioned as you can get, but numerical errors still occur. One common error is loss of orthogonality. A fix for this could be to re-orthogonalize your columns after some number of multiplications. You can do this by just taking the QR decomposition of your matrix after some number of products and taking the orthogonal part. Since your matrices are square, this will cost $O(n^3)$, so comparable to the matrix multiplications.

Comment: Thanks. Is there also something to do with regard to general rounding errors - like working in log space as is commonly done when multiplying probabilities?

Comment: The loss of orthogonality is a result of accumulated round off errors. This should be the only significant source of error since orthogonal matrices are well-conditioned

Comment: Thanks. Are there general good practices for the general case, in which the matrices are not orthogonal? is it possible to perform the product in log space?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. In the general case, the errors get scaled further by the condition numbers of the factors. The multiplication may be more stable if each factor is stored in some decomposition like QR or SVD but that would be inefficient to compute for this many factors

Comment: The OP's matrices are not "orthogonal matrices"  Rather they are the matrices of orthogonal projection operations.